# QGIS Installation on Windows

Tags: qgis, gps, development, qt

I'm newbie to QGIS and to this forum.

I want to develop application using Qt on QGIS to real time updation/mapping of a symbol using GPS co-ordinates.

Initially i have installed QGIS on Windows 32 bit machine.

I'm looking into how to make vector maps in QGIS and the same map to be called on Qt Application to pin/map the location on map with a symbol reference by GPS Co-ordinates.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to read the qgis cookbook:

http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/

There you can read how to program a plugin that suits your needs.

In the section plugins:

http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html

it is shown how to set up a plugin with a user interface that is using qt

Answer (score 3):

@Martin has provided excellent links in order to create plugins for QGIS. To make life a little easier, there is a plugin called **Plugin Builder** which very easily creates all the core files you need for your plugin. You can download and install this from the QGIS toolbar:

[image: Manage and install plugins]

[image: Plugin builder]

There is also a tutorial [here](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html) which describes how to use the **Plugin Builder** (coupled with the QT Designer) and how to create a simple plugin which returns the coordinates of point on the canvas when clicked.

Comment: To install this plugin you have to enable the `Show also experimental` option in Plugins | Settings

Comment: +1 This is tremendously useful. I've wanted to build something like this for Whitebox for quite a long time now. I had something in an older version but haven't had a chance to replicate it in the current version. This gives me some good ideas. You seem to be aware of every hidden corner and crevice in the QGIS world. It never fails to impress!

Comment: Haha many thanks @WhiteboxDev, I still consider myself a 'noob' in this field but I like to share what limited knowledge I know :)